# is this proof and approach correct? $(n$ is a power of $2) \iff \neg(n$ has odd divisors other than the trivial $\pm1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, solution-verification

It is a bicondition and thus I have to prove the both directions. I want to use a direct proof and a proof by contraposition. The direct - in short - is just that The prime factorization of  $n=2^x$  is  $2^x$  and is unique so no other divisors that are not factored - only by power of $2$.

The contraposition is

Assume the opposite, that $n = 2^m$ ($m$ a positive integer) is divisible by the odd number $2D + 1$, where $D$ is a positive integer. That is, $2^m = (2D + 1)(Q)$, where $Q$ is the positive integer quotient.

Since the left side is an even number, $Q$ must be an even number too because the product of two odd numbers is odd. So $Q = 2R$, for a positive integer $R$. Therefore,

$2^m = (2D + 1)(2R)$.

dividing both sides by $2$ yields

$2^{m-1} = (2D + 1)(R)$

Repeat this process until either the power of $2$ on the left side becomes $1$, or the quotient on the right side becomes $1$.

But then the left side will be even but right side will be odd. A contradiction. Therefore the original statement must be true.

Is this proof and approach correct? Any feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: It is (logically) possible that the exponent becomes $1$ before the quotient does, in which case you have $2=(2D+1)R$ for some potentially even number $R$. So both sides are still even.

Comment: Btw welcome to MSE. Here is some info about typesetting math fyi: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @halrankard2 ah yes I see. How would I go about the the contraposition or should I just abort it completly? I am not sure how to finish the proof in the contraposition part. p.s. Thanks for the link I am really new on this site but it seems great!

Comment: Definitely don't abort your approach because it is very nice. Instead think of $2=(2D+1)R$ as a kind of "base case" that your descent argument inevitably reduces to. But now you just have to prove $2=(2D+1)R$ is impossible, which should be easy. (In particular, this is the part where you really get to see why one considers *nontrivial* odd divisors.)

Comment: Hmm.. So should I argue by case at the end point? That 2^1 makes it impossible and the quotient is 1 makes it impossible? So that I follow the whole argument and then "Repeat this process until either the power of 2 on the left side becomes 1, or the quotient on the right side becomes 1." - then i consider the 2 cases and show that they are impossible?

Comment: Yes that should work.

Comment: Okay so I split the proof to 2 small cases. 2^1 first or the quotient hits 1 first. The 2^1 is simple but for some reason im not seeing 2=(2D+1)R  is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Let me summarize the discussion below the question, and continue in a formal answer.

You have a descent argument which inevitably reaches one of two cases:

1. (the $R=1$ case) $2^k=2D+1$ for some $1\leq k\leq m$.
2. (the exponent $1$ case) $2=(2D+1)R$ for some positive integer $R\leq Q$.

Your current proof describes why the first case is a contradiction, but overlooks the second case. For the second case, you want to argue this is impossible using what you know about the parameters involved. In particular, the assumption is that $n$ has a *nontrivial* odd divisor. So $2D+1$ is not $1$. Note that this fact has not yet been used anywhere in the proof. Indeed, the resolution of case 2 is precisely where this assumption becomes relevant. Specifically, if $2D+1$ is not $1$, then what does this say about $D$? More to the point, what does this say about the number $(2D+1)R$, which is supposedly equal to $2$?

Comment: The (other) direct proof - in short - is just that The prime factorization of n=2x is 2x and is unique so no other divisors that are not factored - only by power of 2.

Comment: Oh sorry, I see now you have that at the beginning. I didn't read closely enough, so I'll delete that remark from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof might be okay, but it's a lot simpler than that.

$n$ has a unique prime factorization.  Either that prime factorization contains prime divisors other than $2$ or it does not.

If it does then $n$ is not a power of $2$ and those other prime divisors are all non trivial odd divisors.

If it does not then $n$ is a power of $2$ and all divisors are of the form $2^j$ and are either even or trivial.

So either $n$ is power of $2$ with no non-trivial odd divisors, or $n$ is not power of $2$ and had non-trivial odd divisors.  So $n$ is a power of $2\iff $ $n$ has no non-trivial odd divisors.

(Might be worth noting $[(P \land Q) \lor (\lnot P \land \lnot Q)]\iff (P \leftrightarrow Q).$

(Also might be worth noting that if $n = 1=2^0$ it falls under the category: $1$ is a power of $2$; the unique prime factorization of $1$ contains no prime divisors other than $2$ (and it doesn't contain $2$ either-- it has no prime divisors) and has not non-trivial odd divisors.)

Comment: (P∧Q)∨(¬P∧¬Q)⟺(P↔Q) oh I see. So the proof is basically what you have written in 5 lines since they are logically equivalent.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Either a number is a power of $2$ and has no nontrivial odd divisors... or a number is not a power of $2$ and does have an odd prime divisor.  That's it.  No more. We are done.

Comment: Okay perfect. I just got it. We show that if both p and q are true or non p or non q and that is logically equivalent to the above statement.